# HTTP Load Balancing Firewalls in Google Compute

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, firewall

Is there a way in Google Compute Engine to set up an HTTP Load Balancer behind a firewall? Can this be done using Cloud VPN? For Example, I want to deploy a Load Balancer that limits access to ip addresses within a certain range. In other words, I would like all unwanted traffic to be stopped upon reaching the LB.

Currently I can restrict access with a Network Load Balancer, but it is missing the ability to route different url paths to separate instance groups, and having the HTTPS certificate in one place makes it easier on security.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured this out? I need to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Not yet, I still use the Network LB as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something equivalent to [nginx's `allow` and `deny` directives](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/) on a per-path basis? ([Equivalent for apache is `Allow` and `Deny` from `mod_authz_host`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#host).)

The Compute Engine load balancer is intended to act solely as an HTTP reverse proxy (load balancer), and does not perform access control.

You can set up nginx either on its own, or behind the Google load-balancer to perform authorization and other transformations.

Comment: Yes, but when a request comes through the HTTP Load Balancer, it obtains the Load Balancer's IP address. I was hoping there's a way to set a firewall upstream of the Load Balancer to filter out unwanted source IP's so all traffic through the LB is good

Comment: The HTTP load balancer [sets the `X-Forwarded-For` header](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#components) to allow this sort of filtering.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you'd want the same IP access control list for all paths on the load balancer, or different IP whitelists for different backend services.

Comment: to keep the original ip address, they recommend adding: 

service.beta.kubernetes.io/external-traffic: "OnlyLocal"